# IOS Parse LiveQuery: Error processing message: Optional(POSIXErrorCode: Software caused connection abort)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swiftui, parse-live-query

I've developed an app in SwiftUI where I also use a chat with Parse LiveQuery.
The chat is working perfectly in real time until the app goes in background or the phone screen is closed.
If I receive a notification for a new message and I open the app from the notification then the LiveQuery stopes working and I recieve the error : "Parse LiveQuery: Error processing message: Optional(POSIXErrorCode: Software caused connection abort)"

I register the Message class

```
class Message: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var message   : String
    @NSManaged var receiver  : PFObject
    @NSManaged var thread_id : PFObject
    @NSManaged var produs    : PFObject
    @NSManaged var sender    : PFObject
    @NSManaged var picture   : PFObject

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Message"
    }
}
```

On the ChatView I have .onReceive where I start the function for chat and liveQuery

```
                        var messagesQuery: PFQuery<Message> {
                            return (Message.query()?
                                        .whereKey("thread_id", equalTo: self.mainThread_obj)
                                        .order(byDescending: "createdAt")) as! PFQuery<Message>
                        }
                        self.StartMessagesLiveQuery(messagesQuery: messagesQuery)
```

The func StartMessagesLiveQuery is:

```
 let subscription: Subscription<Message> = Client.shared.subscribe(messagesQuery)        
        subscription.handle(Event.created) { query, object in
            print("Live Query Trigered")
            print(object)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    ///reading object and appending to array}}
```

The only problem is when the app is opened from Notification.

I've there any way to force ParseLiveQuery to reconnect?

Error stack:

```
2021-03-03 10:15:47.442021+0200 App[35496:6350370] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C2] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2021-03-03 10:15:47.449044+0200 App[35496:6350370] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C3] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2021-03-03 10:15:47.449291+0200 App[35496:6350370] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2021-03-03 10:15:47.455008+0200 App[35496:6350370] [connection] nw_flow_add_write_request [C2.1 52.1.38.170:443 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] cannot accept write requests
2021-03-03 10:15:47.455055+0200 App[35496:6350370] [connection] nw_write_request_report [C2] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
2021-03-03 10:15:47.455815+0200 App[35496:6350657] ParseLiveQuery: Error processing message: Optional(POSIXErrorCode: Software caused connection abort)
2021-03-03 10:15:47.456612+0200 App[35496:6350370] Task <F6A87098-D5D3-444B-B656-D1999D5089D1>.<44> HTTP load failed, 42/0 bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53])
2021-03-03 10:15:47.462120+0200 App[35496:6350657] Task <F6A87098-D5D3-444B-B656-D1999D5089D1>.<44> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x282d11830 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x280174aa0 [0x20a814660]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb344692570000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F6A87098-D5D3-444B-B656-D1999D5089D1>.<44>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F6A87098-D5D3-444B-B656-D1999D5089D1>.<44>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://site.b4a.app/classes/_User, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://site.b4a.app/classes/_User, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2021-03-03 10:15:47.462237+0200 App[35496:6350657] [Error]: The network connection was lost. (Code: 100, Version: 1.19.1)
2021-03-03 10:15:47.462335+0200 Bazar[35496:6350657] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.588128 seconds.
```

After this the network connection is restored and the app is functional, only the LiveQuery are not working.

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing the error? Can you share the complete error stack?

Comment: I don't know which line is trowing the error. The compete error stack i will i will put in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think i’ve solved it.
I've modified function StartMessagesLiveQuery:

```
func StartMessagesLiveQuery(messagesQuery: PFQuery<Message>){}
```

Inside the function I had:

```
let subscription: Subscription<Message> = Client.shared.subscribe(messagesQuery) 
subscription!.handle(Event.created) { query, object in ... }
```

Now i’ve modified and put inside the Class

```
var subscription: Subscription<Message>?
 var subscriber: ParseLiveQuery.Client!
```

and in the function i’ve modified with:

```
subscriber = ParseLiveQuery.Client()
subscription = subscriber.subscribe(messagesQuery)
```